# Do you have to be a US citizen to receive the Alaskan Permanent Fund Dividend

Tags: usa, alaska

To receive money from Alaska's permanent fund dividend, you must be an Alaskan resident for at least a year. Does this imply that you must be a naturalized US citizen as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to their website, the [requirements for eligibility](https://pfd.alaska.gov/Eligibility/EligibilityRequirements) are as follows:

> I was a [resident of Alaska](https://pfd.alaska.gov/Eligibility/EstablishingResidency) during all of calendar year 2013;
>
> On the date I apply for the 2014 Permanent Fund Dividend, I have the intent to remain an Alaska resident indefinitely;
>
> I have not claimed residency in any other state or country or obtained a benefit as a result of a claim of residency in another state or country at any time since December 31, 2012;
>
> - I was not:
>
>   - Sentenced as a result of a felony conviction during 2013;
>   - Incarcerated at any time during 2013 as the result of a felony conviction; or
>   - Incarcerated at any time during 2013 as the result of a misdemeanor conviction in Alaska if convicted of a prior felony or two or more prior misdemeanors since January 1, 1997
> - If absent from Alaska for more than 180 days, I was absent on an allowable absence; and
> - I was physically present in Alaska for at least 72 consecutive hours at some time during 2012 or 2013.

The [full regulations](https://pfd.alaska.gov/Content/StatsAndRegs/2014StatandRegWeb.pdf) define a resident as (page 32):

> A person establishes residency in the state by being physically present in the state with the intent to remain in the state indeﬁnitely and to make a home in the state

No mention is made of a requirement to be a US citizen in order to be eligible, implying that it is not a requirement.